# what happens to an injured pokemon shuffled back into the deck

Tags: pokemon

Heracross can perform an attack which forces the opponent to »shuffle his active pokemon back into his deck«.

**What happens if this pokemon is already injured?** I did not find the rules adequate about this—does the injury vanish or does the pokemon keep its received damage?

Comment: The injury just vanishes. Once a card goes back into the deck it becomes like any other card in the deck, a new fresh copy. There's no way to keep track of it anyway - you can't exactly mark the injured card with the amount of damage it's sustained.

Comment: It’s true that keeping track of the card is more difficult and this circumstance suggests your interpretation of the rules are correct. But this does not mean it is—it would be still possible to track by pen and paper for instance.

Comment: What makes you say that? Say you shuffle my Heracross back into my deck, but I have 4 copies of the card. How do you know the next Heracross I draw is the original one shuffled back?

Comment: True! I forgot about the possibility to have more than one exemplar of a card. So your logic is conclusive. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a Pokémon changes zones, The Game essentially loses track of it. If it comes back into play, **it is considered a new/different Pokémon**, even if both players know it is the same card.
So yes, the damage (as well as all other markers etc.) on it would indeed just vanish.

To back it up with rulings from the official Rulings Compendium on http://compendium.pokegym.net/compendium-bw.html:

> Q. If I use Pokemon Communication to put a Pokemon into my deck, am I
>   allowed to voluntarily fail and choose to take no Pokemon out of my
>   deck?
>
> A. The contents of your deck is not public knowledge so the deck
>   search can fail, even if you've just put a Pokemon into the deck. (Feb
>   4, 2010 PUI Rules Team)
>
> ---
>
> Q. Can I play Unown onto my bench, activate its "Farewell Letter"
>   ability to discard it, and then use Revive to put it back onto the
>   bench and use "Farewell Letter" again?
>
> A. Yes, you can. (Dec 3, 2015
>   TPCi Rules Team)

Answer (score 2):

As @allure thanksfully pointed out, there is no possibility to track damage and special conditions of a pokemon shuffled back into the deck when there is more than one exemplar of this very pokemon existent in the deck.

Hence **damage and special conditions vanish** in that case.

Comment: Welcome to Boardgames Stack Exchange! Are you able to provide a source for your answer?

Comment: No I am not. I solely found @Allures line of thinking absolutely conclusive.